# How can I implement layout like this with recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[image]

I use `GridlayoutManager` and override `getSpanSize` method. I was able to implement three and one column in the same recyclerview. But I was not able to implement five columns in the same recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which row will have five column and which has three column so you can use below code

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
 
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if (position > 3)
            return 5;
        else
            return 3;
    }
});
```